How to disable error logging when client.connect(URL) in Socket.IO Client C++ library is unreachable?
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/blob/master/API.md
It keeps outputting to console whenever the server is unreachable.
I want to suppress these messages completely.
[2024-08-27 18:25:18] [error] handle_connect error: Connection refused
[2024-08-27 18:25:19] [info] asio async_connect error: asio.system:111 (Connection refused)
[2024-08-27 18:25:19] [info] Error getting remote endpoint: asio.system:107 (Transport endpoint is not connected)

This doesn't work: client.set_logs_quiet()
I tried building from source with CXXFLAGS+="-DSIO_DISABLE_LOGGING", no luck here as well.

Those log statements are produced by the websocketpp dependency, not socket.io-client itself. Documentation

@Botje yeah I figured that, it's coming from one of the asio libraries.

@Botje thanks for this! I kind of found the solution.

Found the answer. This is kind of a workaround but it's working.
From https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/tree/master source, edit the ./src/internal/sio_client_impl.cpp and append  the m_client.clear_error_channels(websocketpp::log::elevel::all); line within the void client_impl::set_logs_quiet(){ ... } member function body, save the changes, and build this modified source code and use this modified library with your program. In your program, after instantiating the sio::client client;, use the client.set_logs_quiet(); and there will be no errors sent to the stdout/console.
